# How to add 'data-dropdown-content' to menu's ul?

Tags: jquery, joomla, zurb-foundation

It's based on this example from zurb foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

```
    <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">Has Dropdown</a>
     <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
     </ul>

    <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop2">Has Content Dropdown</a>
     <ul id="drop2" class="f-dropdown content" data-dropdown-content>
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
     </ul>
```

I've tried:
 `$( ".f-dropdown").attr('data-dropdown-content');`

It doesn't work.

Could this be what's preventing the child menu from not showing up?

I also have this before body tag:

```
         <script>
           $(document).foundation();
          </script>
```

This is the menu as it is so far: (got all the things inserted with the exception of this question)

```
     <!-- Navigation -->
       <ul class="nav menu button-group">
        <li class="item-101 current active">
           <a href="/social/services/" >Home</a>
        </li>
       <li class="item-106 deeper parent">
         <a class="programs" href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services" >Programs &amp; Services</a>
             <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
               <li class="item-107">
                  <a href="/social/services/index.php/programs-services/child-services-link-example" >Child Services Link Example
                  </a>
              </li>
             </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-108">
         <a href="/social/services/index.php/featured-articles-news" >Featured Articles &amp; News</a></li>
     <li class="item-109">
         <a href="/social/services/index.php/resources" >Resources</a></li>
     <li class="item-110">
         <a href="/social/services/index.php/donate" >Donate</a></li>
     <li class="item-111">
          <a href="/social/services/index.php/contact-us" >Contact Us</a></li></ul>

  <!-- End Navigation -->
```

If you want further background of the question, though I don't think it necessarily pertains to this question, here's my earlier question today:[How to add data-dropdown="drop1" in a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797317/how-to-add-data-dropdown-drop1-in-a-menu)

Comment: Are you importing jQuery aleady? If so are there multiple libraries being imported that could cause conflicts? Have you tried calling the plugin using Joomla coding standards for inserting Javascript? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Lodder, um, yes, I'm importing jquery via this link:  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> but, doesn't jQuery automatically have no conflict?

Comment: No, Joomla doesn't automatically use no conflict mode, this is only possible in Joomla 3.x is you use the proper method as stated in one of my answers a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933

Comment: @Lodder , I am using Joomla 3.x, and my template is custom, ie, all I'm calling so far are these: <?php
//no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access' );
JLoader::import('joomla.filesystem.file');  
$doc   = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/normalize.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/foundation.css');
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/foundation.min.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/foundation.dropdown.js');
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use jQuery to add the `data-dropdown-content` attribute to elements:

`$( ".f-dropdown").attr('data-dropdown-content');` is a *getter* function. You want to *set* the attribute. Try this:

```
$( ".f-dropdown").attr('data-dropdown-content', '');
```

Comment: just tried your statement, and looked it in firebug, this is what it shows: data-dropdown-content="", should it come up with that? If you look at the example above, it's just "data-dropdown-content."

Comment: In chrome, it shows as above. I think that's up to the browser. I assume the plugin is using a selector like `[data-dropdown-content]`, so either would work.

Comment: you're right. Just checked in Chrome, and it shows as it is. In FF, with firebug, it shows otherwise. Hm. It's still not making my drop-down menu work. I wonder why ... is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: no worries. as you've technically answered my question as I've written it out, it's probably up for another post. Hm. Not sure how to frame that question now. But thank you for your clear explanation why I had done it the wrong way.